# How to check data usage of a USB datacard on Ubuntu?

Tags: usb

Are there any tools to check data usage of USB datacard on Linux?
The way can be done on Windows, is it possible on Linux also?

Comment: You mean total traffic through Datacard.

Comment: Are you referring to an USB modem? If so, can you provide your ISP and used modem?

Comment: Yes, total traffic through a datacard.

Comment: @Cumulus007 Idk if you know/heard the ISP I am using. It is MTS and a USB datacard.

Comment: I understand, but what is the make/brand? Try lsusb to identify the USB modem.

Comment: @Cumulus007 

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05a9:2640 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV2640 Webcam
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 19d2:fff1 ONDA Communication S.p.A.

Answer (score 1):

Use [vnstat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/vnstat.1.html)

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

Then first check which Interfaces are available through

```
vnstat --iflist
```

`Available interfaces: lo eth0` , the `eth0` for Wired connection, yours will be different (`wlan0` i guess)

Then run

```
vnstat
```

It will be something like this

```
 eth0 since 05/23/12

          rx:  20.66 GiB      tx:  5.35 GiB      total:  26.01 GiB

   monthly
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
       Jun '12      9.18 GiB |    2.28 GiB |   11.47 GiB |   37.11 kbit/s
       Jul '12      6.35 GiB |    1.48 GiB |    7.83 GiB |   47.50 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated     12.30 GiB |    2.87 GiB |   15.16 GiB |

   daily
                     rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     yesterday    241.20 MiB |  122.44 MiB |  363.64 MiB |   34.48 kbit/s
         today        81 KiB |      54 KiB |     135 KiB |    3.22 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated        --     |      --     |      --     |
```

You can use `vnstat` accordingly ,

```
 vnstat -s   << -s for short output mode

                      rx      /      tx      /     total    /   estimated
 eth0:
       Jun '12      9.18 GiB  /    2.28 GiB  /   11.47 GiB
       Jul '12      6.35 GiB  /    1.48 GiB  /    7.83 GiB  /   15.17 GiB
     yesterday    241.20 MiB  /  122.44 MiB  /  363.64 MiB
         today        35 KiB  /      14 KiB  /      49 KiB  /      --
```

Similarly `vnstat -d` for daily basis record ,`vnstat -h` for hourly basis and you can refer other usage through the [Vnstat Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/vnstat.1.html) .

Another Web Browser based utility  is [NTOP](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/)

Comment: Thanks. it works.
Although it is eth1 rather than wlan0.

Comment: It doesnt let me do that as I don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: Its fine , in future maybe, Thanks though.

Comment: `vnstat -m` : For month

Answer (score 1):

`vnstat` is probably the best way to do this. It can be installed using the following command in terminal:
`sudo apt-get install vnstat`

If you don't want to keep checking the data usage status every time then use:
`watch -n 5 --differences vnstat -d eth0`

It would display the status every 5 seconds in the open terminal with the differences that occur in the values. `-d` is used to display the status of each day and `eth0` is the ethernet used for internet connection (`wlan0` may be used for WiFi and `ppp0` for a USB datacard).